# Cocos2d game crashing shortly after CCCallFunc

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

**Situation:**
I'm getting some mysterious crashing shortly after a CCCallFunc. In short, we have a button. The button has a tag to identify it later. When the button is pressed, we run some actions to animate it, and when the animation is done, we CCCallFunc another method to transition to another scene. We crash shortly after the CCCallFunc. Source and errors below.

**Point Of Crash (in cocos2d source):**

```
// From CCActionInstant.m of cocos2d
-(void) execute
{
    /*** EXC_BAD_ACCESS on line 287 of CCActionInstant.m ***/
    [targetCallback_ performSelector:selector_];
}
@end
```

**Snapshot of Thread 1:**
[image: Thread 1 stack]

**My Code:**
Below is some source taken from MenuLayer.m (a simple menu to display a button).

```
// from MenuLayer.m
// …

@implementation MenuLayer

-(id) init{

    if((self=[super init])) {

    /****** Create The Play Button (As a CCMenu) ********/
        CCSprite *playSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"playbutton.png"];

        CCMenuItemSprite *playItem = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:playSprite selectedSprite:nil target:self selector:@selector(animateButton:)];
        playItem.tag = 3001;
        playItem.position = ccp(160.0f, 240.0f);

        CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:playItem, nil];
        menu.position = ccp(0.0f, 0.0f);
        [self addChild:menu z:0];

    }
}

// ...

- (void)animateButton:(id)sender{

    /*** Run an animation on the button and then call a function ***/
    id a1 = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.05 scale:1.25];
    id a2 = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.05 scale:1.0];
    id aDone = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(animationDone:)];
    [sender runAction:[CCSequence actions:a1,a2,aDone, nil]];

}
- (void)animationDone:(id)sender{

    /*** Identify button by tag ***/
    /*** Call appropriate method based on tag ***/
    if([(CCNode*)sender tag] == 3001){

    /*** crashes around here (see CCActionInstant.m) ***/
        [self goGame:sender];
    }
}

-(void)goGame:(id)sender{

        /*** Switch to another scene ***/
    CCScene *newScene = [CCScene node];
    [newScene addChild:[StageSelectLayer node]];

        if ([[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene]) {
            [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:newScene]];
        }else {
            [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:newScene];
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the animationDone code?

Comment: @Setrio the -(void)animationDone code is included above in my source code for MenuLayer.m right under -(void)animateButton. Can you see it?

Comment: Sorry, for some reason scroll doesn't work :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CCCallFuncN instead of CCCallFun.

CCCallFuncN passes the Node as parameter, the problem with CCCallFun is that you are loosing reference of the node.

I test your code with CCCallFuncN and works ok.

Answer (score 2):

Just a hunch. Besides checking for memory leaks, try to schedule a selector with a 0 second interval instead of directly sending the goGame message. I have a suspicion that director's replaceScene causes a cleanup of the scene and all objects associated with it. That in turn could leave the CCCallFunc action in an undefined state. Although normally it works fine - which is to say that this is just another indication about something sketchy, memory- respectively object-lifetime-management-wise.

Btw, if you support iOS 4 as a minimum, use CCCallBlock instead of CCCallFunc. That's safer and cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for this @LearnCocos2d. It did not work though, sadly (replaced the direct call to goGame with a scheduled call to goGame at an interval of 0.0). Also useful to note is that we don't even get to the director code because the crash happens before we reach that method. I assume this after placing NSLog(@"reached this point"); was never called at the beginning of goGame.